# Slider Control behavior changes

Tags: windows-phone-7

I created a slider in wp7 to control the volume of the backgroundaudio player.

```
<Slider x:Name="VolumeSlider" Height="89" Margin="12,0,24,-20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ManipulationCompleted="OnSoundManipulationChanged" Maximum="100" SmallChange="1" LargeChange="100" Value="75"/>
```

What happens is, I try to manipulate the slider, but the slider just moves a small step, even if I try to move a long distance.
The ManipulationCompleted event is not fired till I remove my finger from the slider, but it as well just sets the small value change.

This behavior happens after navigating one time to another page in my app.
It works again if I restart the app.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this, the solution was posted by Paul Sinnema and worked fine!

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/82897/501068.aspx

```
using System.Windows;  
using System.Windows.Controls;  

namespace ControlClassLibrary  
{  
public class PSSlider : Slider  
{  
    public PSSlider()  
    {  
    }  

    public UIElement GestureListenerBug  
    {  
        get { return (UIElement)GetValue(GestureListenerBugProperty); }  
        set { SetValue(GestureListenerBugProperty, value); }  
    }  

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GestureListenerBugProperty =  
        DependencyProperty.Register("GestureListenerBug", typeof(UIElement), typeof(PSSlider), new PropertyMetadata(null));  

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)  
    {  
        SetHitTestVisibility(false);  

        base.OnMouseEnter(e);  
    }  

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)  
    {  
        SetHitTestVisibility(true);  

        base.OnMouseLeave(e);  
    }  

    private void SetHitTestVisibility(bool visible)  
    {  
        if (GestureListenerBug != null)  
        {  
            GestureListenerBug.IsHitTestVisible = visible;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

}

```
<ct:PSPhoneApplicationPage x:Class="MCRemote.MainPage" 
                       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
                       xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone" 
                       xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone" 
                       xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls" 
                       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                       xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:MCRemote.Converters" 
                       xmlns:ct="clr-namespace:ControlClassLibrary;assembly=ControlClassLibrary" 
                       xmlns:co="clr-namespace:MCRemote.Controls" 
                       xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit" 
                       mc:Ignorable="d" 
                       x:Name="Main" 
                       SupportedOrientations="Portrait" 
                       Orientation="Portrait" 
                       shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" 
                       Loaded="PhoneApplicationPageLoaded" 
                       d:DesignHeight="768" 
                       d:DesignWidth="480" 
                       Foreground="White">
```

...

```
            <ct:PSSlider x:Name="VolumeSlider" 
                         GestureListenerBug="{Binding ElementName=Main}" 
                         Maximum="1" 
                         Minimum="0" 
                         SmallChange="0.01" 
                         LargeChange="0.1" 
                         ManipulationStarted="SliderManipulationStarted" 
                         ManipulationCompleted="SliderManipulationCompleted" 
                         Value="{Binding PlaybackInfo.BoundVolume, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                         Grid.Column="1" 
                         Grid.Row="2" />
```